# Python module PySurfer mne install error

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-16.04, mne-python

I did the installation of MNE following [webpage instructions](https://www.martinos.org/mne/stable/getting_started.html).

However:

```
$ pip install PySurfer mne
```

does not work.

> "ImportError: No module named retrying"

I'm using: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit

Comment: Did you try to `pip install retrying` before calling `pip install PySurfer mne`?